# Meaning of a sentence in David Copperfield

Tags: british-english, literature

> The phaeton was a very handsome affair; the horses arched their necks and lifted up their legs as if they knew they belonged to Doctors’ Commons. There was a good deal of competition in the Commons on all points of display, and it turned out some very choice equipages then; though I always have considered, and always shall consider, that in my time the great article of competition there was starch: which I think was worn among the proctors to as great an extent as it is in the nature of man to bear.

Why is starch involved in dresses of proctors and their competitions? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

Before washable fabrics for stiffening shirt collars etc. were invented, smart men's shirts had starched collars and cuffs. At the time in which this story is set, high collars were fashionable, and they would have been quite uncomfortable to wear.  The proctors competed as to who could have the smartest carriage and the highest starched collars.

Comment: Starched collars and cuffs were typical office wear for men through the 1940s and ‘50s. @Kate You’d make a great moderator!